# SlidingMenu ABS and Android Studio

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-studio, slidingmenu

I have read through a bunch of different Stack Overflow posts and various blogs all offering different ways to get these libraries working with android studio but I have yet to be successful with any of them.

I am currently using android studio 0.2.5.

The current error I am getting when trying to run gradlew assemble:

- What went wrong:

  Execution failed for task ':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock:compileReleaseAidl'.

  > tried to access class com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DependencyBasedCompileTask$DepFileProcessor from class com.android.build.gradle.i
  >   nternal.tasks.DependencyBasedCompileTask

My project structure is as follows:

```
|MyProject
----|MyProject
----|libraries
--------|ActionBarSherlock
------------|actionbarsherlock
----------------build.gradle
------------|actionbarsherlock-fest
------------|actionbarsherlock-i18n
------------|actionbarsherlock-samples
------------build.gradle
------------settings.gradle
--------|SlidingMenu  
------------|library
----------------build.gradle 
----|MyProject
----build.gradle 
settings.gradle
```

All the build.gradle files are below:

MyProject - > MyProject -> build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.3/Parse-1.3.3.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':libraries:SlidingMenu:library')
}
```

MyProject - > libraries -> ActionBarSherlock -> build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
  }
}

allprojects {
  group = 'com.actionbarsherlock'
  version = '4.4.0'

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  tasks.withType(Compile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
  }
}
```

MyProject - > libraries -> ActionBarSherlock -> actionbarsherlock -> build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

MyProject - > libraries -> ActionBarSherlock -> settings.gradle

```
include 'actionbarsherlock'
include 'actionbarsherlock-fest'
include 'actionbarsherlock-i18n'
```

MyProject - > libraries -> SlidingMenu -> library -> build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile project(':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

MyProject - > settings.gradle

```
include ':MyProject', ':libraries:SlidingMenu:library', ':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock'
```

I think that's all the important files but please let me know if I missed one.

Thanks for any advice you can give!

Edit 1:

Made sure all the build.gradle files had:

```
compileSdkVersion 16
buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"
```

as some were different.

Made sure all manifests had:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

I also updated everything the sdk updater tool had to update but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add Dependency to your project in Project Structure 
[image]

Comment: The libraries are not currently marked as modules so I don't appear to be able to add them under dependencies.  Should I move them out of the libraries folder in my project structure and make them there own module?

Comment: This link will help you: (http://armanpagilagan.blogspot.in/2013/07/using-actionbarsherlock-in-android.html)